# Selenium WebDriver and xpath locating inside WebElement

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a page containing multiple forms with their own submit buttons and other elements. While testing the page, I locate the second form

```
WebElement form = getDriver().findElement(By.id("form2"));
```

and then field and submit button

```
form.findElement(By.name("text")).sendKeys("Adding some text here");
form.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();
```

However these xpath locations take effect on the first form. Is it really so that the xpath doesn't work inside a specified element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact Selenium works with the first found by xpath element. If you know exact order number you can add such a number to your xpath `//input[@type='submit'][2]`. Please note that numbering in xpath starts from 1 but not 0. So given xpath will found for you the second input with `@type='submit'`.

Comment: This is incorrect. It will only work if the `<input>` elements are direct children of the same element, so if it works for the OP, then it works by accident only.

Answer (score 1):

Try a relative path:

```
form.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@type='submit']")).click();
```